# SMBus Host controller not enabled

Tags: boot, 14.04, grub2, bash, permissions

I'm using vmware to use my ubuntu

I get SMBus Host controller not enabled

After searching for answers found that I should choose Advanced options for Ubuntu(Recovery mode)

but it even in recovery mode,  it don't ask for root to login

[image]

Comment: If you are running 14.04 as the flag implies it is years past EOL and not supported on this site.